# Blocking IP connections by certain pattern

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

IIS 6.0 with Windows Server 2003. We have bot attack or scanning (low to medium) to our IIS server. Reading IIS logs, we realize that one IP loads our web page in the way shown in the picture:
[image]

We can block that IP on the firewall, but I'm wondering if it's possible to block on IIS by behaviour or pattern, for example, blocking some IP due it's accessing one web page 4 times in a second, and continuously for 5 hours?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what most IDS/IPS systems do... Look for suspicious patterns and block IPs.

Comment: May I ask how to configure that on IIS 6.0 or some link for information?

Comment: IIS can't do that, you'll need an IDS/IPS appliance in addition to IIS.  Typically this run on or behind your firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS can't natively do this, and this function is traditionally handled by an IPS/IDS (actually a Web Application Firewall is more appropriate that inspects Layer 7 traffic and is able to decrypt https traffic), but an ISAPI filter installed in IIS such as [WebKnight](http://www.aqtronix.com/?PageID=99) from AQTRONIX (free/opensource) should be able to do what you ask.  It is similar to [URLScan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc242650.aspx) from Microsoft, but has more functionality.  The following is from the link:

> **Connection control/monitoring**
>
> You can block or monitor traffic coming
> from certain ip addresses or ranges. You can also monitor access to
> certain important files or limit the number of requests coming from a
> single IP address.